# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Logoff user when browser tab is closed - IsPersistent has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

*I know this question seems like it has already been asked, however this is related to ASP.NET Core and not to ASP.NET 5.*

I am trying to get the user logged out when the user closes the browser tab; I am testing this with Chrome and Safari on a MacOS.

Currently when I log in the user, and the browser tab is closed and re-opened, the user remains logged in.

When I log the user In, I Set the `AuthenticationProperties` `IsPersistent` to `false`. Yet the user remains logged in when the browser tab is closed, both on Chrome and with Safari. (The browser is not closed, only the tab).

```
        Task task = HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, 
           new AuthenticationProperties
           {
              IsPersistent = false
           });             
        await task;
```

According to the Docs: [persistent-cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#persistent-cookies)

> "You may want the cookie to persist across browser sessions"

In the case above, I set the IsPersistent to false, and I assume that the
cookie should not survive the session.

As I understand, the browser does not close the session, the server does and this is set to 10 seconds below.

Yet by testing as below, I am unable to get the user to be logged out.

1. Login the user
2. Confirm the user is logged in
3. Close the browser tab, (not closing the browser)
4. Wait more than 10 seconds
5. Open the browser tab and ensure the user is not logged in. **This Fails**

*This might be irrelevant...*
The Starup.cs has this:

```
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/accessdenied";
        });
```

Comment: Was there an answer under asp.net 5. Because I have feeling it will be same answer.

Comment: I think it is not relevant, though. I'll ad some more text to the question.

Comment: THen is sounds like you need to store something like the user name in a session variable.  And then in each control check for that value.  If the session has expired, route to the login page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Session Cookie and the Authentication Cookies are two seperate cookies,
and therefor the `options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` has no effect on the Authentication cookie.

By setting the `ExpireTimeSpan` Authentication cookie options as below, will cause the user to be logged off it the browser is closed, or inactive for more than 10 seconds. Furthermore the `SlidingExpiration` will cause the desired effect of not logging out the user, if active before the expire time, by issuing a new cookie before the old one expired.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/accessdenied";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true; // here 1
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);// here 2
        });
```

The `IsPersistent` property, when set to true, however does not effect the cookie Expire time. e.g. It does not make the cookie not expire.
`IsPersistent` is to survive the closing of the `browser`, `not the tab`.